# How to i change the color of only certain characters in a json file?

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, multilingual, next-i18next

I'm working on multilingual using next.js and next-i18n.
Let me ask you a question through the example below.

Json File

```
{
  "test": "Hi, this string value will change. Thank you"
}
```

example

```
 t("test")
```

So, I want it to change like the image below.
I put a specific character in my json file to separate it, but it doesn't work. 
What should I do?

[image]